# Ceiling Fan Cracked Socket Repair

Tags: electrical

One of the bulbs in ceiling fan cracked and was stuck in the socket. Was easy to get out, but afterwords noticed the socket itself is cracked.

Assuming this is not safe to use. Is this an easy repair? Are the sockets something that can be found at hardware store because Google search has not led me to solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is the ceiling fan. Link below. Looks like lights part of light kit. 40w B10 bulbs.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hunter-Westminster-5-Minute-Fan-52-in-Satin-Bronze-Indoor-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-5-Blade/4332196

Comment: Please _revise_ your question. Don't put information down here in comments. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I'd look at repair parts like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-75W-Candelabra-Base-One-Piece-Single-Circuit-Keyless-Hickey-Mount-Phenolic-Incandescent-Lampholder-Black-10026/301667448

Answer (score 1):

Most fan light kits aren't really serviceable. You're unlikely to find the exact bulb socket you need, and they're often installed with pressed metal, so it would be a challenge to reinstall one.

It's not terribly expensive to replace the light kit (keeping your glass), and they're easy to swap out. There's usually a threaded connection between the fan and the light kit and three wires to disconnect.

Disconnect power at the breaker first.